# Specify Multiple Directories in Notepad++ Find in Files

Tags: replace, directory, notepad++, wildcard, findinfiles

Notepad++'s "Find in Files" is amazingly helpful. But I want to specify a bunch of directories in which the search should take place.

[image]

Above you see me add the wildcards to the "Directory" field:

> C:\*\vc90\*

However my version of Notepad++ doesn't seem to tolerate asterisks in the path.

I have about 30 Visual Studio Projects who's names I want to be grabbed by the first asterisks in the path, but I only want to modify files in the vc90 version of these projects (not vc80, vc100, etc.), and I don't want to have to go individually specify each of the directories.

Is there some other recourse for me?

Answer (score 2):

#### PowerGREP

While it's not Notepad++, and it's not free, [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com/) can do what you're looking for. You can download an evaluation version, which appears to still be working on my machine, months later.

I created a few mock files/folders and it seems to work as you expect. There are options to create backups, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is very nice looking. I was just gonna write a C++ program to do it, but I'll have to check this out

Comment: Yeah, seems to be able to do quite a lot! Hope it's useful.

Comment: The demo license is 15 days of actual use. So if you have used it on less than 15 separate days your license would not have expired yet.

Answer (score 0):

[VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is free and supports wilcards for both files and paths in search/replace operations.